# Show base errors using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have errors on the model as opposed to the model fields, so these are added to errors[:base]. In my simple form code I am using;

```
  <%= f.error_notification %>
```

This shows ordinary errors, but not the base errors. How do I view the base erros?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just add

```
  <%= f.error :base %>
```

which will show the base errors at the top of the form.

Answer (score 12):

`error_notification` accepts a `message` option should you wish to override it using any base error messages.

```
<%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence %>
```

Comment: I'd to add a condition to avoid always displaying an empty red div, though: `if f.object.errors[:base].present?`